# Poor performance when using OpenMP in inner loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following code which is basically a forward substitution of a lower triangular matrix.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_rowptr()->size() - 1; ++i)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int j = matrix.get_rowptr()->operator[](i); j < matrix.get_diagonal_index()->operator[](i); ++j)
    {
        sum += matrix.get_value()->operator[](j) * result[matrix.get_columnindex()->operator[](j)];
    }
    result[i] = sum;
    result[i] = vector1[i] - result[i];
}
```

The first loop goes over the rows and the second one over the columns. The average number of operations in the inner loop is minium 100.
I tried to use OpenMP to parallize the inner loop by simply adding
`#pragma omp parallel for`
But the wall time increased. Is there a way to parallize this peace of code in good way?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: Sorry. I have added the code line.

Comment: More details: how much work are the loops doing ?  How did you time the execution ?  What hardware resources do you have ?

Comment: The outer loop is performed about 50000 times and the inner loop minimum 100 times per outer loop. I measured the time using the high resolution clock before and after calling the function where the loop is called. The hardware is Intel Xeon E5-2640.

Comment: Usually you'd want it the other way around, you don't want to call the parallel region many times and you want them to be as long as possible, 100 is such a small number it might be faster if you simply used a single thread as the overhead of parallelising might take more time than simply letting a single thread do it. On a side note, how are `get_rowptr` and `get_columnindex` defined?

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will try to find another way. The functions get_rowptr and get_columnindex return a pointer on a std vector.

Comment: I was asking because they might be preventing the compiler to use SIMD instructions to process the data, which usually helps a fair bit with most matrix operations. So the question was how they were defined, what they return seems clear.

Comment: The matrix object has three std vectors. One of type double (value) and two of type integer. The vectors are used to store a matrix in CSR format. If this seems not to be the answer, then I am sorry and I do not really understand what you are asking for.

Comment: As Qubit implicitly suggests, why can't you simply parallelize the outer loop (leaving the inner loop serial)? There don;t appear to be any loop carried dependencies there and there would be no need for any OpenMP reduction operations either.

Comment: The above code shows a forward substitution. The inner loop gets data from the result vector which is updated after every inner loop. This seems to be the problem why the outer loop cannot be parallelized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the poor performance is due to the call of small parallel regions in the inner loop. When re-writing the code to use parallelization for the outer loop, the performance increases with increasing number of threads.